# Problems with the database and the Unity project

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

I make a project in Unity with an external database, run the local server with OpenServer, create the project in Unity as OpenGL, but when building the project, connection to the database disappears

```cs
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("QCode", StaticData.CodeQuest);


        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost",form);

        yield return www;
```

Maybe the problem is that the database is located locally, or there is something wrong with the Unity settings...

The connection is implemented with PHP, Unity, OpenServer(MySQL) on localhost.
The database itself is not stored in Unity.

Connection via PHP is implemented as follows.

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Quest-DB;charset=utf8;','root', '123456');
```

I will send all the necessary information, just tell me.

I tried to find the problem on the Internet, but I did not understand what it is related to.

As it turns out OpenServer even gets some requests, at least that's what the log says:
1.localhost: 127.0.0.0.1 [15/Apr/2023:01:15:43 +0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 201 "-" "UnityPlayer/2021.3.14f1 (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.84.0-DEV)"

2.localhost: 127.0.0.1 [15/Apr/2023:01:17:05 +0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 201 "http://localhost:53919/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.3.1.895 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"

In the first case, the request is sent from Unity itself, and in the second, from a created project.

Comment: So whatever machine on the internet you are running this on is expecting to find a webserver on itself with your php scripts. Is this realistic?

Comment: No, but in this case I need my local Unity project to interact with the local server running in OpenServer, before the build all the data from the database is displayed, but not after